# Acrescentar um caractere a uma str em python

Tags: python

Tenho uma data de nascimento onde preciso q o programa leia a informação e digite o dia, mes e ano usando pyautogui. Pra função WRITE funcionar, preciso transformar a data, que é um número inteiro, em uma str.
O local onde preciso digitar essas datas, possuem 2 digitos: 01, 02, 03... 14... 30 e 31.
Quando a str possue 2 digitos (de 10 adiante) o programa roda tranquilamente e digita as dezenas sem problemas, porém quando a data se torna com 1 digito, ele imprime somente uma casa e não consigo digitar o 06, por exemplo e digitando apenas 6 nao da.

```
> > import datetime    
    import pyautogui
> > 
> > data_atual = datetime.datetime.now() 
    day = data_atual.day day =
> > str(day)
> > 
> > pyautogui.write(day) # nesse caso imprime 24 pq hj é 24 mas em dias 1,2,3...9 eu tenho problemas.
```

O pyautogui não imprime numeros inteiros, então existe a necessidade de transformar o numero inteiro em uma str, porém complica em numeros de 1 digito apenas. Uma solução que encontrei pra consertar isso, foi incluir um IF pra todo resultado de 1 a 9:

```
> if day == '1':
>     pyautogui.write('01')  
elif day == '2':
>     pyautogui.write('02')
 .
 .
 . 
elif day == '9':
>     pyautogui.write('09') else:
>     pyautogui.write(day)
```

gostaria de algo mais simples pra inserir um 0 na sting day quando ela tivesse apenas 1 digito sem ter q usar tantas linhas de comando como no if. A inserção do 0 deve vir na frente pra transformar 1, 2, 3... em 01, 02, 03...

Outra solução q achei foi:

```
if day <= '9':
        day = ('0' + day)
else:
    day = day
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fstring](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
import pyautogui
from datetime import datetime  
  
data_atual = datetime.now() 

pyautogui.write(f'{data_atual.day:02}')
```

*fstring* é um literal string prefixado com `'f'` ou `'F'`. Essas strings podem conter campos de substituição que são expressões delimitadas por chaves `{}`.

Opcionalmente um especificador de formato pode ser incluído após a expressão usando `:` para iniciar esse especificador.

No caso o especificador de formato `02` informa que será formatado um inteiro cujo a representação string deverá ter ao mínimo dois caracteres e os caracteres faltantes serão preenchidos com `0`.

Para saber mais veja [Mini linguagem de especificação de formato](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

Também é possível usando o método [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) passando o argumento `"%d"` como um [código de formatação](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

```
import pyautogui
from datetime import datetime   

data_atual = datetime.now() 

pyautogui.write(data_atual.strftime("%d"))
```

`datetime.strftime()` converte objeto para uma string conforme um formato fornecido e o código `%d` solicita o dia do mês como um número decimal completando, se necessário, com zero a esquerda.

Comment: Sem palavras... me destravou novamente... não sabia dessa de documentação...ajudou muito! Vou começar a olhar isso agora e vou fazer um curso!... vlw

Answer (score 2):

Todos esses if's realmente é desnecessário. Talvez seja interessante você verificar a documentação do módulo datetime, existe um método que simplifica o que está tentando fazer...
"strftime" retorna uma string com valores e formato especificados. Para o atributo day retorna sempre string com dois números.

```
import datetime    
import pyautogui

data_atual = datetime.datetime.now()
day = data_atual.strftime("%d")
pyautogui.write(day)
```